# How to parse expressions to access POJO properties?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Suppose I am checking POJO properties in my unit tests as

```
assertNotNull(pojo1.getX().getY().getZ());
assertEquals(pojo2.getA().getB().getStr(), "foo")
assertEquals(pojo2.getC().getD().getNum(), 100)
```

Now I have to read the properties and their values from a text file, which contains:

```
pojo1.x.y.z
pojo2.a.b.str = foo
pojo2.c.d.num = 100
```

What is the best way to convert those text expression into the java code above?

Answer (score 1):

Use OGNL or [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) for this.